# What's an absent-minded drawing called?

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a specific word which is used for drawings (like smilies, cars, cartoons, etc) which we made to pass the time, say while talking with someone or in a lecture. I need to know the exact word for it.

Answer (score 95):

It's called a **doodle.**

> A rough drawing made absent-mindedly:
>   *the text was interspersed with doodles*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/doodle)

Comment: What about *Google Doodles*? Just kidding

Comment: Interesting side note: "doodle" first entered English through the 1936 movie "Mr. Deeds Goes to Town". The exact quote in context can be found on [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0027996/quotes)

Comment: @njuffa You should send that to OED. Their earliest citation is 1937: R. M. Arundel *Everybody's Pixillated* p. ix,   A ‘doodle’ is a scribbling or sketch made while the conscious mind is concerned with matters wholely unrelated to the scribbling.

Comment: The OED editors seem to be aware of the movie, but presumably they need printed references. The OED2 starts its list of citations for the intransitive verb "doodle" as follows: **1937** *Lit. Digest 26* June 19/3 'But everybody doodles.' So Gary Cooper, as Longfellow Deeds, in 'Mr. Deeds Goes to Town', defended himself. He wasn't crazy because he drew squares and circles on scraps of paper -- he was just 'doodling'.

Answer (score 14):

It's the activity known as **doodling**.

Comment: ...and the picture itself 'a doodle'

Answer (score 11):

Another possibility is **scribble**.  The main difference is that doodles are more likely representational while scribbles are generally abstract, though this is not necessarily true in either case.

Comment: The main difference is "doodle" is cooler sounding.